# Android to Ubuntu 16.04 audio

Tags: bluetooth

I have ubuntu and my android connected to each other over bluetooth, is there a way I can send all audio (audio in and audio out) from my android phone to my ubuntu pc?  I want to use my headset this if possible?

Comment: try installing `Blueman`. It adds a feature to use your bluetooth device as audio sink (if supported by the hardware)

Comment: I have blueman already installed, so I have an option to connect to audio source, is that the correct option I should use?

Comment: Yes, you can try that option(Can't recall the precise name of the option to use, been a while). Just make sure that audio sink plugin is enabled in preferences/plugins section.

Comment: so after doing some research that option does not exist or work on 16.0.4.